# Very long time needed to access and parse file on a web server

Tags: time, server

I'm currently having an issue and I don't understand what causes it.
I could narrow it down to a very simple php script :

```
$start = microtime(true);
yaml_parse_file("someYamlFile.yaml");
print(microtime(true) - $start);
```

It's a 63 mb file I'm trying to parse.
When I try that script with Wamp server, on my own computer, it takes only a few seconds to complete.
However, when I run the same script on the remote server hosting my website, it takes about 170 seconds to run.
If I run it a second time, it only takes a few seconds though.
After several minutes, without any visitor to the website, if I run that script again, it takes 170 seconds!
I'm no expert when it comes to servers. Any idea on what could cause this?
Thanks.

Edit :
I tried fopen() and fread() instead and the issue remained.
It took more than 2 minutes to open and read the file the first time, and only a few seconds the second time.
It turns out the problem comes from accessing the file and not from yaml_parser.
I changed the title but still have no clue about what's causing the issue.

Comment: I assume you mean 63mb file, do you really need to parse that on every request?

Comment: @Jiml :
63 mb indeed.
Eventually the yaml file won't be parsed since the information required from the file is stored in a database.
I just didn't want to create a huge data table as only a fraction of the file will be used. But I don't know which part will be used until users start to use it.

Comment: Honestly, I would expect this to take no less than three minutes on a shitty web server. Just transfer the data to a database.

Comment: Oh and the different times needed for opening and parsing are probably PHP's internal caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you said is reasonable on a cheap server, on which the drive may be very inefficient.

Files are normally opened using sendfile, which uses the Linux Cache.
The loads being slow again after several minutes makes sense --> the cache is invalidated.

None of these issues are related to PHP :-)

I would recommend you put that file on a Ramdisk, so that it sits in RAM instead of on the disk.

/dev/shm is the default ramdisk on modern linux distribution ==> create a folder under it and place the file there.

As for putting the data in Memcache(where it should be): requires the Memcached pecl extension

To add(run once):

```
$m = new Memcached;
$m->addServer('localhost',11211);

$m->set('app_config',yaml_parse_file("someYamlFile.yaml"));
```

To load(run in your script):

```
$m = new Memcached;
$m->addServer('localhost',11211);

$data = $m->get('app_config');
```

Comment: I couldn't see the /dev/shm folder while connected via ftp access so I tried to create a folder and copy the file there with a php script.

Comment: It made me wonder : Am I alllowed to put files there?
It worked but the process took 2 minutes...
However, parsing the file from that location only took a few seconds!
It seems like you're right...
Files are supposed to be stored on fast SSDs...
I can't believe that an emulated server on my 8 years old computer can parse a file almost 50 times faster than a server charging me to host my website.
I know it's hosting other sites but still.
Thanks.

Comment: It turned out the file was probably still in PHP cache because of the copy process.
I tried to read it again after a few minutes and it took quite some time.
Cheap server indeed. I guess there is not much I can do.

Comment: You can make sure the cache doesn't invalidate ...
Put a task in crontab( cron -e ) that calls the PHP script once every minute.
This obviously is a short-term solution, and the long-term one would be putting it in a database. preferably memcache. Read about memcached: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/turbocharge-your-website-with-memcached--net-23939 . Putting it in memcached shouldn't take you too long

Comment: Thanks for memcache. I'll definitely look into it.
The server have I/O limits. They limit the number of Input/Output operations per second to avoid performance issues.
I'll end up using the database and probably memcache.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Added memcached code to complete the answer.
Just install memcache and the memcached pecl extension and copy the code to use.